# how to use Google speech to text api in Auto Hot Key scripting?

Tags: autohotkey

I have tried Google speech to text api with python and it is working properly, Is there any way that we can integrate Google speech to text api into Autohotkey scripting?

Answer (score 0):

While you can submit JSON and other data to API's through various URLs in AutoHotkey, I know of no way to hand off data like audio to an API like Google's.

Your best bet would likely be using AHK to call the Python script and go from there.